# Free Mac OS X application for downloading an entire website

Tags: macos, software-rec, website, download

Is there any free application for downloading an entire site installable on Mac OS X 10.6?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've always loved the name of this one: [SiteSucker](http://www.sitesucker.us/).

**UPDATE**: Versions 2.5 and above are not free any more. You may still be able to download earlier versions from their website.

Comment: I like this one too. Simple to use interface also.

Comment: Ditto! this thing works, has a nice gui and is easy to configure....

Comment: It's not free. On the App store, they're asking $5.

Comment: @JohnK looks like they changed policy for 2.5.x and above, but earlier versions are still available for free from http://www.sitesucker.us/mac/versions2.html.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamHankiewicz is right, you can download 2.4.6 free from their site here - http://ricks-apps.com/osx/sitesucker/archive/2.x/2.4.x/2.4.6/SiteSucker_2.4.6.dmg

Comment: FYI: 2.4.6 still works great on macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Answer (score 54):

You can use [wget](http://www.merenbach.com/software/wget/) with it's `--mirror` switch.

```
wget --mirror –w 2 –p --HTML-extension –-convert-links –P /home/user/sitecopy/
```

man page for additional switches [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wget).

For OSX, you can easily install `wget`(and other command line tools) using [`brew`](http://brew.sh).

If using the command line is too difficult, then [CocoaWget](http://code.google.com/p/cocoawget/) is an OS X GUI for `wget`. (Version 2.7.0 includes wget 1.11.4 from June 2008, but it works fine.)

Comment: I need software man, don't want use wget

Comment: wget is software, and it's the most flexible.

Comment: wget is brilliant software, it's a one-stop-shop for any downloading you might fancy.

Comment: ok then Tanx for your answer

Comment: Wget is great. I use `wget --page-requisites --adjust-extension --convert-links` when i want to download single but complete pages (articles etc).

Comment: as of v1.12, --html-extension was renamed to --adjust-extension

Comment: @JohnT Does `wget` files downlaod all CSS/JS/Images and fonts too?

Comment: @Volatil3 yes, it does.

Comment: Note: you can install `wget` by running `brew install wget`

Comment: As of version 1.2 `--HTML-extension` has replaced by `--adjust-extension`

Answer (score 4):

HTTrack: http://www.httrack.com.

Found in macOS [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/httrack).

Provides ports to Windows, Linux-es, and macOS. Command-line utility on (seemingly?) all OSes, GUI options on some.

Answer (score 3):

SiteSuuker has already been recommended and it does a decent job for most websites.

I also find [DeepVacuum](http://deepvacuum.en.softonic.com/mac) to be a handy and simple tool with some useful "presets".

Screenshot is attached below.

-

[image: Simple interface with "presets"]

Comment: Awesome tool, just what i needed!

Comment: It's really simple and works very well!

Answer (score 2):

http://epicware.com/webgrabber.html

I use this on leopard, not sure if it will work on snow leopard, but worth a try

Answer (score 1):

[pavuk](http://pavuk.sourceforge.net) is by far the best option ... It is command line but has an X-Windows GUI if you install this from the Installation Disk or download. Perhaps someone could write a Aqua shell for it.

pavuk will even find links in external javascript files that are referenced and point these to the local distribution if you use the -mode sync or -mode mirror options.

It is available through the os x ports project, install port and type

`port install pavuk`

Lots of options (a forest of options).

Answer (score 1):

[A1 Website Download](https://www.microsystools.com/products/website-download/) for Mac

It has presets for various common site download tasks and many options for those who wish to configure in detail. Includes UI + CLI support.

Starts as a 30 days trial after which is turns into "free mode" (still suitable for small websites under 500 pages)

Answer (score -4):

Use curl, it's installed by default in OS X. wget isn't, at least not on my machine, (Leopard).

Typing:

```
curl http://www.thewebsite.com/ > dump.html
```

Will download to the file, dump.html in your current folder

Comment: Main problem with that is that that's downloading **the homepage**, not the entire website.

Comment: Well, look at the man page

Comment: Last I checked, `curl` doesn't do recursive downloads (that is, it can't follow hyperlinks to download linked resources like other web pages). Thus, you can't really mirror a whole website with it.

Comment: Well, then do a quick script to get the links, we are in command line land right? Otherwise, just use a tool with a graphical front end.

Comment: A quick script, I dare you ;-) Last time I checked, `curl` also didn't even download the media embedded within that single web page. So: I'd love to see that script that, for a single page, 1) fetches all images etcetera and 2) rewrites the HTML to refer to those local copies... ;-)

Comment: (And its name *is* cURL... I think John T's edit were really improving your answer.)

Comment: There is no difference, and it's a erroneous way to write. Although often used in marketing and so on. It's a name, so I suppose the correct way would be to capitalize the first letter. Look up the man page in a terminal and you see what I'm talking about, it's either curl or Curl. But what are you arguing about here, something of substance? I think not.