# OS X App for Web Spidering & Mirroring

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec, website, mirroring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Mac OS X application for downloading an entire website](https://superuser.com/questions/67604/free-mac-os-x-application-for-downloading-an-entire-website)

What's the best Mac OS X application for mirroring web sites?

I'm looking for something as powerful as wget and as easy as iPhoto. Or maybe, What Would Steve Jobs Use? Command line utilities need not apply.

Comment: I guess this is answered at yesterday's "Free Mac OS X application for downloading an entire website" at http://superuser.com/questions/67604/free-mac-os-x-application-for-downloading-an-entire-website

Answer (score 0):

Never used it on Mac OS myself, but I do use [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/), and it has nice out-of-the-box defaults for mirroring. Their FAQ says it compiles just fine on OS X.